# Canon EOS 5DS - unable to set aperture in Manual (M) mode

Tags: canon

I have an EOS 5DS, which has different controls than former EOS 5D's such as the Mk ii. When I put the camera in Manual (M) mode, I'm able to set shutter speed using the Main Dial, however when I attempt to modify the aperture using the Quick Control Dial (rear of camera), the dial instead adjusts the aperture offset. I suspect it's something to do with camera setup (some other option has modified the dial behavior). I'm looking for insights from others on how to diagnose and correct the issue!

Comment: Do you have HDR option activated?

Comment: Never fails, ask the question ... find the answer. The setup script I followed overrode the quick select's function when metering to control ISO. Once I modified it to control aperture ... problem solved.

Comment: *It's perfectly legit on SE to answer your own question.*  Please post the answer as an answer, so we can upvote it and get you even more rep! It will still be useful for the next person googling for help.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably got  the *Quick Control Dial* remapped to control some other function of the camera instead of leaving the default function of that dial set to changing the selected *Aperture Value (Av)*.

Check your settings under the Custom Functions 3 tab [C.Fn3: Others] (the third orange tab with an outline of a camera body above an index scale) → [Custom Controls] → [Quick Control Dial (symbol)] to verify that you have the *Quick Control Dial* set to control *Aperture Value (Av)*. Some of the other options are *AF point direct selection*, *Direct AF point selection: Vertical*, *Set ISO speed*, and *Tv (Time Value i.e. "shutter speed")* as well as *Av (Aperture Value)*.

It's all covered in the [*EOS 5Ds/EOS 5Ds R instruction Manual*](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/9/0300018669/01/eos5ds-5dsr-im-en.pdf) starting on page 413.